# How can I serve the content over HTTPS

Tags: angular, https

I created an app and I deployed it on DigitalOcean and I have a SSL Certificate. There are 2 separated servers, 1 for the angular which has a balancer loader for the https redirection and the one for backend, but when I open the website I got this in console.

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.mirrorate.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://165.22.187.137/api/posts?pagesize=2&page=1'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

Can someone explain me this? Or how I solve this, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can't make an https calls via http in a case of security.

To resolve your issue you can setup nginx to proxy your http backend urls via https.
With nginx server you will need to call your api like https://your_domain/api/some_path and nginx will proxy your request to api host, that you will set in config

Example config. PS - don't forget to change your certificates files paths:

```
# if you have sockets
upstream socket {
    ip_hash;
    server host:port fail_timeout=0;
}

server { 
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on;
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    client_max_body_size 50M;

    # server_name YOUR_SERVER_NAME
    ssl_certificate /fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /privkey.pem;

    include /options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /ssl-dhparams.pem;

    location /ws/ {
        proxy_pass http://socket;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }

    location /api {
            proxy_pass http://host:port/api;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your angular app is over HTTP(S) can't make request to HTTP server because break the protocol HTTPS and the browser does not allow that. You need a HTTP(S) backend or a HTTP frontend.

Comment: backend can be setup without https. We can proxy our requests from domain server with nginx

Comment: no. browser over https never trigger a  XMLHttpRequest to a http api.

Comment: you need to read my comment again. I didn't say that browser can call http api over https. I just want to say that api may setup without http if we will proxy http api calls to https with nginx for example.

Comment: that's means that api calls will be over https but to proxy server, not to backend

Comment: where u get fullchain.pem and privkey.pem? if is a self signed certificate the browser will block the request. and you need enable manually your certificate in the browser an then the browse will make the requests. but if you restart the proxy need enable again in the browser.